# Flutter: Persist BottomNavigationBar and route user to the correct screen depending on the selected index of the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, flutter-scaffold

I want the BottomNavigationBar to persist and the user to be sent to a different screen depending on which index that they have selected and that index highlighted on the BottomNavigationBar.

The way I'm attempting to do this is to change the body value of the `Scaffold` according to the currently selected index of the `BottomNavigationBar()`. I am able to highlight the selected index of the `BottomNavigationBar()` once it is selected but the body is not routing to the appropriate widget.

The current method referenced for `onTap:` in the `BottomNavBar` correctly highlights the selected index but does not route to the correct widget.

There is an unused method (`_switchScreen`) in my `BottomNavBar`. Inserting this as the value to `onTap:` for the `BottomNavBar()` appropriately routes to the correct screen but then I have to have the `BottomNavBar` rebuilt on every view and is inaccessible behind the `BottomNavBar` which is referenced in the `NavModel` (Navigation Model).

Here is my `BottomNavBar()`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../screens/Add_Media_Screen.dart';
import '../screens/Profile_Screen.dart';
import '../screens/Venture_Feed_Screen.dart';
   
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _switchScreen(index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, VentureFeedScreen.routeName);
        break;
      case 1:
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProfileScreen.routeName);
        break;
      case 2:
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddMediaScreen.routeName);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff84d1da),
        accentColor: Color(0xff62c2a2),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xff84d1da),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          //Index 0
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.explore,
            ),
            label: 'Discover',
          ),
          //Index 1
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              // color: Color(0xff84d1da),
            ),
            label: 'Profile',
            // backgroundColor: Color(0xff84d1da),
          ),
          //Index 2
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
            ),
            label: 'Add Media',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `NavModel`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../screens/Profile_Screen.dart';
import '../screens/Venture_Feed_Screen.dart';
import '../screens/Add_Media_Screen.dart';

import '../widgets/BottomNavBar.dart';

class NavModel extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/nav-model';
  @override
  _NavModelState createState() => _NavModelState();
}

class _NavModelState extends State<NavModel> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final tabs = [
    VentureFeedScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    AddMediaScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: tabs[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting it into two different classes would not work in this scenario. In the `NavModel()` class for the `body:` property of the `Scaffold`, I was attempting to update the value of the `tabs` list according to the `_currentIndex` which had a static index value of 0. I thought that by calling on the `BottomNavBar()` class and setting the `onTap:` value to update according to the `_onItemTapped` method that it would update the `body:` value according to what was defined in the `_onItemTapped` method within the `BottomNavBar` class. This was incorrect.

The code was running correctly as I had defined it: the `body: tabs[_currentIndex]` of the Scaffold was calling on the correct logic - display the item at the 0 index of the tabs list. While this was occurring the index of the BottomNavBar was updating to reflect the correct user selected index and values thus causing confusion of why the BottomNavBar selected index was updating while the body of the `Scaffold` remained a constant.

Here is the correct code:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/navigator-model';
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> tabs = [
    VentureFeedScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    AddMediaScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: tabs.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xff84d1da),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          //Index 0
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.explore,
            ),
            label: 'Discover',
          ),
          //Index 1
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              // color: Color(0xff84d1da),
            ),
            label: 'Profile',
            // backgroundColor: Color(0xff84d1da),
          ),
          //Index 2
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
            ),
            label: 'Add Media',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am, however, yet to see if the `BottomNavBar` persists on navigation to another screen (have not yet built that functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is the behaviour of the [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) class, is that right? Make PageView the body of your scaffold, and pass `tabs` as children to the PageView.

Comment: Not quite. PageView enables a carousel-type action. I'm trying to have the BottomNavBar control the navigation. Whereby clicking on "Discover" (index 0) I'm routed to `VentureFeedScreen()`, clicking on "Profile" (index 1) I'm routed to `ProfileScreen()`, clicking on "Add Media" (index 2) I'm routed to `AddMediaScreen()`.

Comment: If you don't want the carousel-type UI, AnimatedSwitcher should do the trick, but this does not make use of the Navigator. If you really want to use the navigator for the routing, I suppose you should define a bottomnavbar for each page and make a custom routing transition that makes it seems as if only the Scaffold's body is changing and not the bottomnavbar (a FadeTransition might do)